# ARC semantic issue: Pointer to non-const type 'id' with no explicit ownership

Tags: objective-c, pointers, automatic-ref-counting

I have this Objective-c interface declared in a header file:

@interface DelegateChain: NSObject

{
@protected

```
id          * delegate;
NSUInteger            numberOfDelegates;
NSUInteger            sizeOfDelegatesArray;
NSMutableDictionary * hashs;
```

}

...

end this is a piece of code in the implementation file that use the variable delegate:

...

```
if( NULL == ( delegate = ( id * )realloc( delegate, ( sizeOfDelegatesArray + 10 ) * sizeof( id ) ) ) )
    {
        /* Error management... */
    }
```

the problem is that if I try to compile the code, the compiler responds with this error for the header file:
ARC semantic issue: Pointer to non-const type 'id' with no explicit ownership

Reading other posts, I've tried to delete the * for id *delegate because the type id is already a pointer, but in this case the program get crashed.

Comment: The complete code is taken from this site. This code implement a mechanism for multiple delegate. http://www.eosgarden.com/en/articles/cocoa-delegate-chain/